# Infinite Scroll com PHP array

Tags: php, rolamento, array-associativo

Tenho um array PHP com cerca de 10.000 chaves organizado assim:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13154
            [photo_file] => 013154.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7885
            [photo_file] => 007885.jpg
        )
)
```

E no arquivo HTML tenho um loop que transforma o array em tags de imagens assim:

```
<?php
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $photo_file = $array[$key]["photo_file"];
    echo "<img src='$photo_file' />";
?>
```

Eu queria criar um Infinite Scroll a partir deste array PHP para evitar carregar todas as imagens de uma só vez quando a página fosse acessada. Alguma idéia da melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Talvez eu pudesse converter o array PHP para JSON e depois para uma variável Javascript para usar JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode carregar todo o array de uma só vez usando ajax (talvez com jQuery), o php (servidor) retornaria o array codificado em json, o javascript se encarregaria de ouvir o evento onscroll para exibir o conteudo no html.

Ou você pode usar outra abordagem, em que o php não retorna todo o array de uma vez só. Mas em vez disso retorna aos poucos, por exemplo, 10 indices por vez. Para isso, o cliente em javascript teria que mandar na requisição ajax o ultimo indice acessado e o servidor manipularia o restante.

Comment: Obrigado Juven, eu acabei adotando a segunda abordagem sua (LIMIT + AJAX + GET), mais clássica e com mais conteúdo. Para isso, adicionei uma condicional na query, pois antes estava usando PHP para filtrar os resultados e montar o array.